# How do I set the padding's of containers relative to the height of the browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a mobile menu laid out in a grid based format. The menu consists of 6 items. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

When I drag the window up I would like the padding to change so that all 6 items are still shown within the contents of the window.

Here is how the HTML is structured:

```
  <div class="top-menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="mobile test">
                    <a href="/" title="test">test</a>
                </li>
                <li class="test">
                    <a href="/test.html" title="test">test</a>
                </li>
                <li class="test">
                    <a href="/test.html" title="test">test</a>
                </li>
                <li class="test">
                    <a href="/test.html" title="test">test</a>
                </li>
                <li class="test active">
                    <a href="/test.html" title="test">test</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="last test">
                    <a href="test.html" title="test">test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And here is the SASS:

```
 .top-menu {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        top: 71px;
        left: 0px;
        background: rgb(41, 50, 53);
        ul {
            float:none;
            li {
                width: 50%;
                cursor: pointer;
                float:left; 
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 22% 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #515c64;
                border-right: 1px solid #515c64;
                text-align: center;
                &:nth-child(even) {
                    border-right: none;
                }
                a {
                    line-height: initial;
                    height: auto;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also a link to the demo - https://jsfiddle.net/4szbvseb/

Any help / advice is appreciated.

Comment: We would like to see some `CSS` too. It will be helpful if you create a **DEMO** for this..

Comment: Just add the SASS now - I'll throw up a quick demo. Here - https://jsfiddle.net/4szbvseb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I've edited your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4szbvseb/2/) to what I think does what you want it to do.
All that needed to be done, was:

1. Getting rid of the `padding`
2. Adding a `height` of 100% to html, body and .container
3. Making .top-menu stretch to 71px from the top and 0 from the bottom
4. Giving all the 'li' elements a `height` of 33.3%

And you're done :)

Hope this helps